# Ошибка запроса: [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "GO"

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc

Пишу скрипт, создающий БД в MS SQL. Запрос сгенерирован из СУБД, и при выполнении из неё же, прекрасно работает, но при выполнении из скрипта, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "GO". (102) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

сам скрипт:

```
import os, subprocess
import pyodbc


def req_sql():
    driversql = '{SQL Server}'
    req =  """
USE [master]
GO


CREATE DATABASE [testtets4]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'testtets4', FILENAME = N'Y:\\Data\\testtets4.mdf' , SIZE = 512000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'testtest_log4', FILENAME = N'Y:\\Data\\testtest_log4.ldf' , SIZE = 256000KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [testtets4].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO


ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE [testtets4] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO

                """

    print(req)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ip-adress;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;PWD=pass11;Trusted_Connection=YES')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(req)
    cursor.close()

req_sql()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых команда `GO` не является частью SQL Standard - это команда обрабатывается SQL клиентом, которым вы пользуетесь. `SQL Server` (серверная часть) будет воспринимать `GO` как ошибку синтаксиса.

Во-вторых `PyODBC` не умеет выполнять скрипты или множество SQL команд. Он умеет выполнять один SQL запрос/команду и в этом случае в конце SQL команды **не нужно** ставить `GO` или `;` или другой разделитель.

Поэтому в качестве решения вы можете выбрать один из следующих вариантов:

- самому парсить SQL скрипт, разбить его на отдельные команды, например по строке `"GO\n"` и в цикле запускать отдельно каждую команду.
- сформировать команду для запуска SQL скрипта из командной строки и запускать весь скрипт целиком используя утилиту с `CLI` (Command Line Interface).